# Times Square calendar XML file error

Tags: android, xml, calendar, runtime-error

I am trying to implement the [Times Square calendar](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) into a fragment. I created a new Android project and added the jar [libraries](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.squareup%22) . I also followed the git hub instructions and added the necessary code to my project. Here is my code.

```
package com.example.timessquare;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView;



public class TimesSquare extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_times_square);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.times_square, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_times_square, container, false);

        Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

        final CalendarPickerView calendar = (CalendarPickerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.calendar);
        calendar.init(new Date(), nextYear.getTime());

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

And the xml file code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.timessquare.TimesSquare$PlaceholderFragment" >

<com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
  android:id="@+id/calendar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:paddingLeft="16dp"
  android:paddingRight="16dp"
  android:paddingBottom="16dp"
  android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
  android:clipToPadding="false"
  android:background="#FFFFFF"
  />
```

Here is the LogCat error that i keep getting.

```
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910): Process: com.example.timessquare, PID: 1910
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.timessquare/com.example.timessquare.TimesSquare}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at com.example.timessquare.TimesSquare$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(TimesSquare.java:64)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     ... 11 more
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     ... 25 more
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/anim/abc_fade_out.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f040001
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2252)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:817)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView.<init>(CalendarPickerView.java:101)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     ... 28 more
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag alpha
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:146)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXml(ColorStateList.java:129)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2248)
11-02 14:28:41.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     ... 30 more
```

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here ... 2019 :D
The Solution is to use it as local project sadly then in settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', ':gtcalendarmodule'
```

and of course in app.gradle:

```
implementation project(':gtcalendarmodule')
```

:gtcalendarmodule - in your case would be name of the library